# ionic tabs are not hide whenever keyboard is open

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic development. i implement form based application.whenever keyboard is opened my tabs come to keyboard upper side.

need to hide tabs whenever keyboard is opened.please help me.

thank you for advanced..!

**here my tabs code**

```
<style>
.keyboard-open .hide-on-keyboard-open {
  display: none;
}
.keyboard-open .tabs.hide-on-keyboard-open + .pane .has-tabs, .keyboard-open .bar-footer.hide-on-keyboard-open + .pane .has-footer {
  bottom: 0;
 }
</style>

<ion-view view-title="{{headerObj.produceDetails}}" hide-back-button="true">

  <ion-content>
    <form  role="form" name="myForm">
      ---------
    </form>

  </ion-content>

  <div class = "tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-striped tabs-color-gray hide-on-keyboard-open">
    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.farmerHome">
      <i class = "icon ion-home"></i>
      {{headerObj.home}}
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.farmersideRecords">
      <i class = "icon  ion-compose"></i>
      {{headerObj.records}}
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.farmerSideDiscussions">
      <i class = "icon  ion-person-stalker"></i>
      {{headerObj.discussions}}
    </a>
    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.farmerMaps">
      <i class="icon ion-map"></i>
      {{headerObj.map}}
    </a>

    <a class = "tab-item" ui-sref="app.farmerSettings">
      <i class = "icon  ion-gear-b"></i>
      {{headerObj.settings}}
    </a>

  </div>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

For us to properly address this question can you provide more info? Like your version of Ionic and the device/os you're having this issue on? Also, please include all relevant code, like your [page].ts code.

Just for your info, this tab issue is a known issue with cordova on Android which they haven't been able to fix yet. However, there are multiple do-it yourself workarounds which you can try. Like the following:

Workaround 1: 
Make your app fullscreen in Android by modifying your ionic config.xml file within the `<platform name="android">` tags to include `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />`

Workaround 2:
Trigger a css class when someone clicks on the input, hiding the tabs. If you want examples of how this can be done see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7047

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is on android, this could help you. In the ionic config.xml, add the following lines in the platform name="android" tag.

```
<platform name="android"> 
  <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge"    target="/manifest/application/activity"> <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" /></edit-config>
  ...the rest of the android configs...
</platform>
```

This will prevent the keyboard to push up everything and simple overlay the keyboard on the content. So the behaviour will be the same or similar to the ios keyboard

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. Your answers need to be specifically tailored to each question. If multiple questions are duplicates of each other, flag them as such rather than answering them all with the same answer.